# Configuring multiple ip address to point to azure webapp

Tags: azure, networking, dns, webserver, azure-web-app-service

Sorry if this may be too basic, I am a newbie and i have not found any solution from Azure documents.

So i have a webapp in azure with a virtual ip address, a custom domain and linked to a vlan.

Currently when i access the virtual ip address i get the message

"Error 404 - Web app not found.

The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure App Service region. This could be due to one of several reasons:"

I would like to be able to go to an ip ( can be the virtual ip address) and be able to access the web like the way i access it via the custom domain.

Also i would like to have multiple ip addresses to point to my web app.

A clear step by step instruction will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want bind multiple domain with your webapp ? if yes, then there is a solution

Comment: @NeerajSharma if by domain also means an ip address then yes, how do do that? I just like to point a static dedicated ip to my azure web app.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve that you require direct IP address access? I imagine there is a better way... and the only way you can have multiple IP addresses on Azure is to use large VMs with multiple Nics - this will get *very* expensive

Comment: I am to integrate the web app with a mobile payment platform (mpesa in kenya) which requires me to send 2 ip address of my server, i assume the will be send post request to my server using ipaddress. BTW can an a record help? @MichaelB

Comment: I don't know anything about mpesa (apart from the little a quick google showed) but I find it extremely unlikely that they don't have an alternative to providing IP addresses. It is very likely that they will accept either an A record or a CNAME record. Do you have a link that shows this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use Azure App Service, your apps are deployed in a shared environnement with several apps sharing the same IP.
To redirect requests to your app, the system needs your app hostname (default azurewebsites.net or custom domain). This is why you can't use the IP directly.

If accessing your website through an IP and having multiple IPs for a single website is a requirement, you might need to consider Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: is there a way to transfer a webapp to a virtual machine?

Comment: No. With Azure Virtual Machine, you have to setup the network, your OS, your web server, your frameworks, your deployment mechanisms, ...

Answer (score 0):

> With ip address you can only configure your cname in host provider. In host your can create awverify Cname.

[image: Manage Custom Domains]

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have not understood your answer?

Comment: I trying to say that you can't use virtual ip address for your web app, but you can add multiple sub-domains